# Passing value through anchor tag using JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

*This question is a little long so that it would be clear, thanks in advance!*

## Introduction:

I currently have a Bootstrap Modal which contains an `<iframe>`. The modal is launched from an anchor tag.

However, the link of the `<iframe>` depends on a PHP variable, `$id` which is dynamic as it is queried from MySQL.

---

## Question:

How can I pass the value of `$id` to the `<iframe>` in Bootstrap Modal, through `data-value` or is there any other ways?

---

## Code:

- **Bootstrap Modal**

  ```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h2 class="modal-title">Edit Status</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe src="https://example.com/page/?id="></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- **Anchor Tag** (To launch the modal)

  ```
  <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php $print id; ?>" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>
  ```
- **PHP Code** (Sets the variable, `$id`)

  ```
  <?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){
      list($id, $content) = $row;
  ?>

    <tr>
      <td>
      <p>
          <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php $print id; ?>" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>
      </p>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

---

## Elaboration:

The `$id` needs to be passed through the `<a>` tag:

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php $print id; ?>" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>
```

So, if the `$id` is `26`, the `<iframe>` should go to:

```
https://example.com/page/?id=26 // id needs to be 26 as $id is 26
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `<a type="button"`

Comment: @mplungjan Oh noted, thanks

Comment: Why not `<a href="https://example.com/page/?id=<?php $print id; ?>" target="iframeName"` ? or just `<iframe src="https://example.com/page/?id=<?php $print id; ?>"></iframe>`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks a lot, I tried it and it worked :) Do you want to write it as an answer?

Comment: try <button onclick="return openpopup(id);">Open</button>and in javascript function openpopup(id){ 
//user your id here document.getElementById('id_of_modal_popup').modal('show')}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
<a href="https://example.com/page/?id=<?php $print id; ?>" target="iframeName"
```

? or just

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/page/?id=<?php $print id; ?>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the `src` of the iframe manually?

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php $print id; ?>" data-target="#myModal"
onclick="
document.getElementById('iframe-id').src = $(this).data('id');
"
>Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)